# How to get StackPanel height before rendering?

Tags: silverlight

In my software (silverlight 3 application) I create a StackPanel in the code, then add objects to it. Is it possible to get its height before rendering? If I try properties like "Height" or "ActualHeight", it's all zeroes...

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, well asked. Helped me out greatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried reading the `DesiredSize`?  If that contains 0, try calling `Measure` passing in a `Size` structure containing large values for `Height` and `Width`, then reading the `DesiredSize`.

Note that the `DesiredSize` isn't necessarily what the containing element will allow it have but I suspect it will give you the information you are after.

Comment: I know this is from a fair while ago but thank you. Your answer has made my week. I just wish I could have found it sooner! +1 (shame I can't +more)

Answer (score 0):

The panel needs to be rendered before you can get the height back. Then you need to use the `ActualHeight` property. `Height` is used to set the *desired* height of the element.

I don't know of any way to "prerender" elements.